# Can I transfer a raided hard drive that is currently on a Windows 2008 R2 server to my Ubuntu Server 14.04 without losing content?

Tags: windows, vmware

I currently have a Windows 2008 R2 server that I am using as a file share. The W2k8R2 server and the Ubuntu server are separate VM images. What I would like to do is unmap the raw mounted hard drive from the Windows machine (NTFS file type) and mount the drive to the Ubuntu server and keep the files intact. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

Yes.

> What I would like to do is unmap the raw mounted hard drive from the Windows machine (NTFS file type)

I doubt this is needed(?) You should be able to mount it in Ubuntu and test if all works first before unmap'ing it in Windows.

But ...

> Will it go flawless?

is a more interesting question. Backup. And make another backup. Make sure you can restore the backup. Did it end up in a mess? Restore the backup. (not likely though ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the help, Rinzwind. I meant to get back to you sooner. The swap was really quite easy. Flawless even. I did backup everything before I made any changes to the drives... I am really liking the access speed that I am getting from Ubuntu on the local network.